# Адаптивная верстка на Jquery: Медиа запросы или resize?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, адаптивная-верстка

Когда я пишу подобный код:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 761px)').matches) {
}
```

То в скобках изменения происходят только при загрузке страницы, а уже при изменениях размера загруженной страницы ничего не изменяется. Решил брать размер окна при помощи функции `resize` вот так:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var widthWind = $(this).width();

    if (widthWind <= 750) {}});
```

Скажите, я на правильном пути или есть лучшая альтернатива? Ведь функция resize вызывается много-много-многократно.

Comment: Если в обработчике события `resize` код будет оптимизирован (не будет кучи бессмысленных и беспощадных "тяжёлых" операций при каждом вызове обработчика), то это вполне нормальный подход.

Comment: А есть альтернатива?

Comment: Можно, например, просто раз в Х миллисекунд (`setInterval`) проверять ширину и производить соответствующие действия.

Comment: Лично я использовал бы медиазапросы. Это стандартный подход, он логичней, удобней для последующей правки, не требует лишних вычислений, тем более ежесекундных (для мобильных устройств это довольно критично), если скрипт не загрузится, верстка не поедет, ну и, наконец, верстка должна быть версткой, а скрипты - скриптами.

Comment: @qtm а что делать если медиа запросы на js работают только в момент загрузки страницы, но не работают при изменении окна (прочтите начало моего топика). Или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Если вы все-таки решили делать медиазапросы на JS, а не на чистом СSS, то я согласен с @Regent

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ по поводу медиа запросов и почему они не работали динамически.
[Ответ здесь](http://3wave.com.ua/news/23-ispolzuem-media-zaprosy-s-pomoschyu-javascript.html).

```
var handleMatchMedia = function(mediaQuery) {
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
        // если менее 480px или равное, то выполняется код между скобок 
    } else {
        // обратное условие, т.е если более 480px
    }
},
mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 480px)');
handleMatchMedia(mql);
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia); 
//запускается каждый раз, когда заданное разрешение медиа запроса достигнуто
```